# Do we have any event in asp.net where controls are not initialized

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, events

I want to redirect to a page without performing any task on the present page. I think it would be good, if I redirect without loading any control on the page. So I need an event, where controls have not been initialized yet.

Comment: What's the business rule to redirect?

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for `PreInit` event, Please have a look at
[Life-Cycle Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for - `PreInit` is called on the page only and is the earliest event you can use. Then `Init` for each control, then `Init` for the page. The control values from viewstate are set during `InitComplete`.

Answer (score 2):

You might try one of the application-level events in Global.asax - for example Application_BeginRequest.  Something like

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains(...))
    {
        Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx");
    }
}
```